# Implementing AddAssign for a custom type: 'binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type'

Tags: rust

I'm very new to Rust and want to use it to rewrite some of the simulations I use for work. I am trying to implement my own version of [hyperdual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number#Generalizations) in Rust, as the existing libraries don't quite fit my needs. To that end, I created a struct to hold a scalar value and a vector of scalar values:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Infinitesimal<F>{
    value : F,
    diffs : Array1<F>
}
```

To be more thorough, `Array1` comes from the crate `ndarray` and is derived from its struct `ArrayBase<S,D>`. This does implement both [`Add`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27a%20ArrayBase%3CS2%2C%20E%3E%3E-for-%26%27a%20ArrayBase%3CS%2C%20D%3E) and [`AddAssign`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-AddAssign%3C%26%27a%20ArrayBase%3CS2%2C%20E%3E%3E-for-ArrayBase%3CS%2C%20D%3E), if I am reading the docs correctly. For reference, the latter is defined as

```
impl<'a, A, S, S2, D, E> AddAssign<&'a ArrayBase<S2, E>> for ArrayBase<S, D> {
...
}
```

I successfully implemented the `Add` trait without any issue

```
impl<F: Add<Output = F>> Add for Infinitesimal<F> where
    Array1<F> : Add<Output=Array1<F>>{
    
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            value: self.value + rhs.value,
            diffs: self.diffs + rhs.diffs,
        }
    }
}
```

On the same way, I can successfully define and compile the `AddAssign` trait in much the same way.

```
impl<F: AddAssign> AddAssign for Infinitesimal<F> where
    Array1<F> : AddAssign{

    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: Self) {
        (*self).value += rhs.value;
        (*self).diffs += rhs.diffs;
    }
}
```

However, at runtime, something goes awry and I cannot actually use the `+=` operator on a mutable instance of my struct. When I try to perform the simple operation, I am met with an error.

```
    let mut x:Infinitesimal<f64>= Infinitesimal::new(1.0);
    x+=Infinitesimal::new(1.0);
```

(`::new(a)` just sets `value` to `a` and `diffs` to a zeroed array)

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `Infinitesimal<f64>`
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     x+=y;
  |     -^^^
  |     |
  |     cannot use `+=` on type `Infinitesimal<f64>`
```

I have tried writing the trait more like it appears [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) to no avail. I have also attempted this mess that compiles, but is not only redundant, but also gives me the same `[E0368]` error.

```
impl<F> AddAssign<Infinitesimal<F>> for Infinitesimal<F> where
    F:          AddAssign<F>,
    Array1<F> : AddAssign<Array1<F>>{

    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: Self) {
        (*self).value += rhs.value;
        (*self).diffs += rhs.diffs;
    }
}
```

This might be a simple issue. At this point, I thought it better to ask more experienced developers whether there are any obvious issues that I'm not able see yet. Would I be able to have some help?

Comment: What is `Array1` and did you implement `Add` and `AddAssign` for it?

Comment: Sorry, `Array1` comes from the crate `ndarray`. I'll add more details in the post.

Comment: From adding more detail to the post, I found that `AddAssign` is implemented for `Array1` in such a way that the right hand side takes a reference. I am working on incorporating this into my next attempt. If this is the issue, I'm surprised that it was not caught by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@cafce25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442760/cafce25) for your question, as it helped me look at the docs more carefully. The `AddAssign` defined for `Array1` takes a reference for the RHS:

```
impl<'a, A, S, S2, D, E> AddAssign<&'a ArrayBase<S2, E>> for ArrayBase<S, D> {
...
}
```

I have modified my own implementation to match, adding the appropriate lifetimes where needed. It works well now!

```
impl<'a, F> AddAssign<&'a Infinitesimal<F>> for Infinitesimal<F> where
    F:          AddAssign<&'a F>,
    Array1<F> : AddAssign<&'a Array1<F>>{

    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: &'a Self) {
        (*self).value += &rhs.value;
        (*self).diffs += &rhs.diffs;
    }
}
```